# create MSI for windows service in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have created a windows service in visual studio 2012. I can install the service using installutil, but I need to distribute the service to a client.

How can I build a MSI?  There are wwalk throughs in vs2008, but they don't seem to apply to 2012, as 2012 has install shield limited edition and I cannot find Custom Actions anywhere..

Comment: Check out [WiX - the Windows Installer Toolkit](http://wixtoolset.org/) - free XML-based installer that creates `.msi` as its output

Comment: You could use the standard service control tool sc.exe as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085856/using-sc-to-install-a-windows-service-and-then-set-recovery-properties

Comment: you can also create a .bat that uses installutil, and distribute that to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Do you *have* to distribute an MSI?

If all you want is to install the service then the application itself should do it. Use a [`ServiceInstaller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Add  a `main` argumnet so when you run `app.exe /install` it isntalls the service (and perhaps `/uninstall` removes it).

The following topic explains the details: [How to: Add Installers to Your Service Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The [`ServiceInstaller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has code example.

You *should* use an MSI if you have more complex requirements, if you want your app to appear in the Control Panel/Add-Remove programs, if you want to add 'Repair' installs, if your installation needs to provide options (CLI or UX).

Comment: are you saying that I should add another project to my service project and make that new project a console application and then from their call the service installer?  I have followed on how to add installers to your service application

Comment: You can make your service application be also the service installer, no need for two projects. Just switch in `main`.