# Script to set services to have a recovery program

Tags: windows, powershell, service, cmd

I'm having a few issues writing a script to modify the recovery options for a remote service - i.e. add a executable to run on error.

It will have one command line argument

```
sc %machinename% failure Bla.ServiceName command= "\"E:\Program Files\App\SendEmail.bat" {0}
```

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085856/using-sc-to-install-a-windows-service-and-then-set-recovery-properties), but I can't seem to get it to work as I'd expect.

Anybody have any pointers - similarly if this is easier in C#/PowerShell I'd be happy to consider looking at those options.

Just had another try based on suggestions - the below works but I'd like to remove the "-" if possible. If I do I get an invalid option from the command prompt.

```
 sc %machinename% failure Service command= "\"E:\Program Files\App\Monitoring\SendEmail.bat\" "Service-is-down-on-env""
```

**Edit...**

It seems I didn't test the obvious adding a slash at the end. For those who are wanting to do something similar it should be:

```
 sc %machinename% failure Service command= "\"E:\Program Files\App\Monitoring\SendEmail.bat\" Service is down on env"
```

Thanks guys, I knew it might provoke some thought if I wrote it down!

One thing I did notice I can't do is make the message appear as one command line argument - is there something I'm missing there?

Comment: Was the remote service originally installed using 'srvany.exe' by any chance?

Comment: Sure a typo but you forget \" -> "\"E:\Program Files\App\SendEmail.bat\""

Comment: "Can't get it to work" is an insufficient problem description. What result do you get, and how does it differ from the result you were expecting?

Comment: Sorry, you are right - it wasn't a good explanation. It was at midnight my time! I'll update the question.